# add admin path to symfoy back end with React js

Tags: reactjs, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm currently working on symfony 4 project with React js to handle admin panel .
I used Webpack Encore to connect React JS  .

the path of The React JS app is :

```
my_project_symfony/
```

And i have an api in :

```
my_project_symfony/api
```

The React JS is supposed to present the admin interface so it must be protected by admin role .

My security config is :

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern: ^/api/login
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        json_login:
            check_path: /api/login_check
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
    api:
        pattern: ^/api
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        anonymous: true
    refresh:
        pattern:  ^/token/refresh
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
```

With this configuration how can i protect my React JS admin interface with admin role and at the same time allow role user to use my api ?

I want to :

```
my_project_symfony/ReactJsAPP  // Protected by admin role

my_project_symfony/api// Protected by user role
```

Comment: Read the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-url-patterns-access-control

Comment: I read it, but i want create an admin route. could i prevent use to authenticate if he's not an admin ?  i mean in the React Js appp i prevent user to generate token if he's not admin